# Ubuntu Server - Websites randomly do not respond

Tags: server, apache2, dns

I have a server that is running Ubuntu Server, Apache2, Railo, mySQL, Tomcat, and Icecast/EZStream

My issue started last week. I have 3 websites pointed to this server with the same DNS, IP address and they are almost identical.

Website A - Railo website with light traffic
Website B - WordPress with medium traffic
Website C - Blank index.html

The issue that I am having is that occasionally I get a Page Not found due to DNS errors for these sites. It was happening to all of them but I switched my DNS to a different company. This solved the issue except for Website B.. Website B I can access it on all of my PCs but I cannot access it with IE on my Windows 8 Phone. I can, however, go to the other sites without any problem on my phone. It only happens for an hours or so then it works again. Is it still caching from when I changed the DNS? Could there be some sort of max connection problem in Ubuntu or Apache?

Comment: I am not sure if this question belongs to the scope covered in [Help - What topics can I ask about here?](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) . I guess it would be more appropriate in [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's something like "max connections" you should check the error logs from your apache server during that time: `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or where ever you configured your error logs.

To check the dns-problem, you can go to several dns lookup services, just type "online dns lookup" in Google and check if the results are correct. Specially check this when the problem happens next time.